# How to select multi controllers in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Here is my storyboard:
[image]
and I know it looks crazy , so I plan to use storyboard reference to move the right part of the storyboard in to a new storyboard. and I googled ,it says press the shift can multi selected controllers ,but it dose not work.

so how can I move multi controllers at same time?

I have tried to use mouse ,but it only selected 5 controllers in the upper part 。

[image]

[image]

But I want to select all of them.

Comment: Did you want to move the storyboards to another project or to another storyboard in same project

Comment: I want to move them to another storyboard in same project @VigneshDavins

Comment: but yes , I also think to know how to move them into another project would be great too . I want to learn both.

Comment: If you want to select all of them then press `Command` button hold it and then click whatever controllers you want ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select them by dragging mouse:
[image]

And then press key Command + C to copy them, 
then open the second Storyboard, press key Command + V to paste them.

Comment: I have tried , but it don't work. only select part of controllers in the area.( I update the question and add some more details.)

Comment: oh I check it again. it work fine but the UI visual only show 5 effect.

Comment: @Neko, the 5 effect doesn't matter, it actually selected all of them in rectangle. Just paste them to 2nd storyboard, and check if they are all copied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
Select controllers you want to copy
Press Command + C
Open your second storyboard file
Press Command + V
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy no any key is required just select using mouse
i post the gif..[image]

Comment: I have tried , but it don't work. only select part of  controllers in the area.

Comment: i have addd the gif see the gif

Comment: i can selecet all 7 controllers at time

Comment: oh I check it again. it work fine but the UI visual only show 5 effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hold down Option and scroll mouse wheel until minimum resolution, 6.25%
2. Click and Drag to select all view controllers - or ones you want to copy.
3. Click Edit->Copy or Use Ctrl+C
4. Go to Target Storyboard.  Click Edit->Paste or Ctrl+V.

I tested this with about 40 controllers,looks like you have around that much. Old question, but new answer! :). In case anyone still looking.

Also I key-bind Option+Z to "Zoom to Fit" and this centers and displays all controllers with the Interface Builder canvas.